# Is it bad to mention being dropped from full-time to part-time when looking for a new job?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, new-job, job-change

I work for a company where I once was Salary before the laws changed, then dropped to hourly, and now I work part time as they doubled the work force and gave everyone part-time with 3 day weekends.

I need the money so I have to find another job. My worry is that even though I was not dropped to part-time due to bad job performance, the future employer may see or think that if the question comes up why I am looking for a new job with more hours during a specific time frame.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**"They cut my hours"** has to be one of the oldest reasons to look for work that there is.

I wouldn't worry about it if I were you.

*If* it comes up in an interview, just tell them the truth - the company cut everyone's hours.

If I were the interviewer, I wouldn't have a problem with this.  You're a hard worker, they cut your hours, you want to work more.

Comment: +1 This puts the most positive spin on a position so many people can relate to.  "Gee, we have a hard worker who is ready willing and eager" would be what would go through my mind.  Best answer possible.  Brief, direct and right to the point.  Bravo!

Comment: This really shouldn't be a problem if it was done across the board as it doesn't reflect on you personally but is a reflection of what the company is trying to do. This is especially true if this is to try to avoid some new regulations such as having to offer health care to all full time employees. Don't want to offer everyone health care, just make everyone part time.

Comment: Lets also not call it spin. It is true. Whether or not it might be the whole story is less important as long as you were honorable...which is the point of the question